# How to extract .iso file using Win32/MFC API?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

We have C++ Win32/MFC application, where I need to extract .iso file. I am not able to find any API.

Please consider I cannot use PowerShell as we wanted to run our application in Windows Server 2008.

It would be great if we can do it without using any third party library.

Is there inbuilt support in Windows Programming to extract iso file?

Comment: Windows 10 (and maybe 8?) can mount .isos as standard, prior to that you'll need a third-party tool like 7zip.

Comment: PowerShell works just fine on Server 2008. What do you mean you cannot use it?

Comment: The IMAPI (Image Mastering API) supports ISO 9660, Joliet and UDF file systems, IFileSystemImage is the work horse.  This is endlessly easier if you let a file system driver take care of it so you can just mount the .iso file as though it is a drive.  Buy, don't build.

Answer (score 5):

No version of Windows prior to Windows 8 (or the server variant, Server 2012) had the native ability to mount ISO files. You couldn't do it from Explorer, and there was no hidden API function. IMAPI supports *burning* an ISO, but not mounting one as a local disk.

In order to do this, you will need a third-party library. A quick Google search didn't turn up any promising results. Unfortunately, Stack Overflow is not a recommendation engine. You will have to do your own research. If all you need is to extract data from the ISO, you can use something like [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html).